# Android MapView gets out of memory error when zooming

Tags: android, android-mapview, out-of-memory

I have an application which uses map activity as a part of whole application, and I get Out of Memory Error When I zoom in and out. I have only one overlay item. Any idea how to solve this ? Here is my xml below, it's quite nested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/contact_layout" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:apiKey="..."
    android:clickable="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phone_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mail_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bus_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bus_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/twitter_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation_bar_without_back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header_navigation"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/anatolia_logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/..." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/call_button_without_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/call_button" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_bar_without_back"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_layout_background" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/info_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LogCat Trace**

```
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size   exceeds VM budget
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at   android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) 
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at     com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.createSnapshot(ZoomHelper.java:444)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.doZoom(ZoomHelper.java:151)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.doZoom(ZoomHelper.java:140)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.doZoom(MapView.java:1517)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.doZoom(MapView.java:1526)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView$6.onZoom(MapView.java:1481)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$4.onClick(ZoomButtonsController.java:274)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at andrd.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at andrid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
     09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    09-03 11:43:20.752: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: this is a bit long. please try to reduce the code to a simple example that causes the same problem/

Comment: Also, do you face it on real device, or on emulator?

Comment: @AlexN I face it on real device and also in emulator.

Comment: @njzk2 I cannot make the simple example by reducing the code above, cuz I don't know what causes it.

Comment: just remove stuff until you figure out what is the smallest code you can provide that crashes.

Comment: @njzk2 see my edited question, I removed almost half of the code and I still get OOM error.

Comment: I found the solution by reading lots of tutorial and article about this issue and this [link](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/outofmemoryerror-and-drawable-t17271.html) is also helped me to solve it. Hope it helps to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ImageViews nested within your layout.
Unfortunately Image-loading and Bitmaps can be a PITA.
ImageViews are known to cause OutOfMemoryErrors. Especially when they get filled with Bitmaps from code.

To solve the problem, remove the ImageViews and check whether the error still occurs.

If it solves the error, rethink your strategy of displaying images on the MapView. Also using [density-dependent](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) resources might help to solve the problem to some extent.

Edit: After seing your stacktrace, which says: "bitmap exceeds VM budget" I'm sure that your Image-loading strategy requires improvment.

Comment: I will try to remove some of my image views and see if it still occurs, but I need to use these image views somehow , do you have any idea how to show these images ?

Comment: Yes. Read the third paragraph of my answer. This is a possibility to solve your problem.

Comment: But I'm already using quite small images for this image views, I have around 5-6 images and the biggest one is 65x65 pixels.

Comment: I have removed almost all of the image views in this layout, there is only map view left and I still get the same OutOfMemory Error. Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Comment: Did you add any overlays that contain images to your map?

Comment: So that should also not be the problem... Maybe you have loaded some BIG Images prior to displaying the MapView and did not dispose them properly?

Comment: I actually have tab host and 5 tabs, map view is the last tab, maybe I used some other bitmaps within the other tabs and they are allocating the heap ? So do you have any idea how can I unbind the drawables from xml layout when changing the tab host ? maybe in their onPause method I can unbind and then bind them back onResume, do you have some opinion ?